# Differences in stability between Ubuntu LTS and Debian Stable

Tags: drivers, nvidia, bluetooth, mate, debian

I've been using Ubuntu for several years, from my beginning in Linux to today with Ubuntu 16.04. I've started doing more advanced configurations (with Bluetooth, networks, built from source packages and the like), and I'm not sure that Ubuntu can handle it. I'm thinking of moving to Debian Stable because I seem to develop inexplicable problems with Bluetooth, graphics, Compiz, and others. I'm wondering if I will run into the same problems on Debian (using MATE)? Is Debian that much more stable, and can I still install my most used programs (Eclipse, Chrome, MATE, proprietary Nvidia drivers, and the like)? I need something that will work on my ThinkPad P50s with minimal problems, without running into strange issues every six months that usually result in an OS reinstall. Which is better  for me?

Comment: "inexplicable problems" and "strange issues" is a bit on the vague side. So the current answer would be: Maybe, maybe not.

Comment: You're asking too many questions at once, and some of those questions are subjective or not well defined.

Comment: I'm just trying to get an idea of what I should do. Most of my problems are like Bluetooth adapters disappearing for a few hours and ethernet networks auto-connecting wrong. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both Debian Stable and Ubuntu LTS are stable releases.  In terms of how they develop and deploy a release there are minor differences in policy between the two but by and large their release policies are pretty similar.  There is no logical reason why one would be significantly more bug-free than the other.